# Getting Duplicate Values With Distinct

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct

Hi I'm using this query to subtract values from a table using data from the same table with different parameters, but I'm getting duplicate values. Can anyone see what is wrong here?

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.BMF_VOTE BMF_VOTE,
       O.BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY,
       O.BGT_ACTUAL_EXPEND - S.BGT_ACTUAL_EXPEND ,
       O.BGT_PREV_ESTIMATE - S.BGT_PREV_ESTIMATE ,
       O.BGT_EST_YEAR1 - S.BGT_EST_YEAR1 ,
       O.BGT_EST_YEAR2 - S.BGT_EST_YEAR2 ,
       O.BGT_EST_YEAR3 - S.BGT_EST_YEAR3 
  FROM BGT_MOF_FROM O, BGT_MOF_FROM S
 WHERE (O.BMF_MAINDIVISION = '100' AND O.BMF_SUBDIVISION = '300')
       AND (S.BMF_SUBDIVISION = '220' AND S.BMF_MAINDIVISION = '100')
```

Comment: Provide sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no join on the tables; that may be where the dupes were coming from. A clearer way to say what you want would be with sub selects ( aliased as O and S below), joined on BMF_VOTE and BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY:

```
SELECT 
   O.BMF_VOTE, O.BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY,
   O.BGT_ACTUAL_EXPEND - S.BGT_ACTUAL_EXPEND ,
   O.BGT_PREV_ESTIMATE - S.BGT_PREV_ESTIMATE ,
   O.BGT_EST_YEAR1 - S.BGT_EST_YEAR1 ,
   O.BGT_EST_YEAR2 - S.BGT_EST_YEAR2 ,
   O.BGT_EST_YEAR3 - S.BGT_EST_YEAR3 
FROM 
  (
   SELECT * FROM BGT_MOF_FROM
   WHERE BMF_MAINDIVISION = '100' AND 
         BMF_SUBDIVISION = '300'
   ) O
  JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM BGT_MOF_FROM
   WHERE BMF_SUBDIVISION = '220' AND 
         BMF_MAINDIVISION = '100' 
   ) S
   on 
   O.BMF_VOTE = S.BMF_VOTE and
   O.BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY =  S.BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY
```

fixing your code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.BMF_VOTE BMF_VOTE,
   O.BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY,
   O.BGT_ACTUAL_EXPEND - S.BGT_ACTUAL_EXPEND ,
   O.BGT_PREV_ESTIMATE - S.BGT_PREV_ESTIMATE ,
   O.BGT_EST_YEAR1 - S.BGT_EST_YEAR1 ,
   O.BGT_EST_YEAR2 - S.BGT_EST_YEAR2 ,
   O.BGT_EST_YEAR3 - S.BGT_EST_YEAR3 
FROM BGT_MOF_FROM O, BGT_MOF_FROM S
WHERE 
   (O.BMF_VOTE = S.BMF_VOTE and O.BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY =  S.BMF_OPERATING_AGENCY) 
   AND 
   (O.BMF_MAINDIVISION = '100' AND O.BMF_SUBDIVISION = '300')
   AND 
   (S.BMF_SUBDIVISION = '220' AND S.BMF_MAINDIVISION = '100')
```

Comment: I found a solution from Ed Baker without joins, but wanted to test yours to learn, but when I run it I get a missing keyword error.

Comment: wait i this i see I didn't correct the one part let me try again.

Comment: Great I got it working too. I just had to edit the table name and remove a extra bracket that sneaked its way in there. Going to try your second code now.

Comment: It worked flawlessly. I'll be saving both so that I can learn from them thanks!

Comment: you've got a good eye for my typos. I fixed the table names and the extra ). Happy to help. You'll likely hear that nested sub-selects are slow..I figure we should be as clear as possible and get the correct result. Then rewrite to optimize, if needed, ensuring we get the same result. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're missing any joining clauses for the two tables, without knowing the data it should look something like:

```
FROM BGT_MOF_FROM O, BGT_MOF_FROM S
WHERE O.key = S.key
```

Obviously replace the key with the actual column name. If you are trying to do a semi-cartesian product (slow and bad), you should wrap the query into a sub query then run a distinct on top of it.

Comment: I feel so stupid now for not noticing this. I could feel that there was uniqueness missing and I couldn't figure out what. THANKS!

Comment: No problems, I totally understand!